# If I run TOR as a root does that break my anonymity?

Tags: kali-linux, tor

I'm having trouble running `tor`.  It says the tor browser bundle should not run as a `root`.  I know if I changed the script from 0 to 1 it would work.

My question is if I change the scrip does that break my anonymity?

Answer (score 2):

No, but it puts you in risk if any error in Firefox/Tor gets you hacked and then the evil one has maybe root access. It's no advantage to run it as root, so just create an ordinary user only for tor usage and start TorBrowser via `su`, if you need to start it from root account.

Comment: I guess if there is a vulnerability in Tor Browser, the anonymity could be broken (even with a non-root user and maybe with a different user also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/45574/running-browser-as-different-user-in-linux#45604) if the user has some personal data with firstname and lastname on his computer. The best thing would be to run Tor Browser on a separate computer with no personal data or use something like LXC.

Answer (score 2):

No running as root will not have any effect on anonymity.

[See here for why not to run as root](https://askubuntu.com/q/16178/587552). However, I do note that Kali Linux by default runs as single-user, root access by design [Should I use Kali Linux?](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux). Be aware of the dangers of running anything as root. It may be a pain to type in sudo  when using kali, but I suggest to create a user that can use sudo, and to type it in every time anyway, only when necessary, or at least to run it in virtualbox.

There are good reasons why programs such as wireshark have been modified to run without root privileges, [Wireshark Capture Privaleges](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges), to limit the damage it and its vulnerabilities may allow, this is especially true for any programs that access the internet.

Comment: I also read this on Kali website (https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-root-user-policy): `the default Kali user is “root”, and no non-privileged user is created as a part of the installation process`.
So it means that in Kali Linux, even the default web browser Firefox runs as root? This would be a serious security vulnerability that could be exploited if Firefox has a vulnerability and is running as root... (even if running as Live CD or Live USB, it could still erase the whole hard drive)
At least I am using Kali Linux in VirtualBox so there is no risk of running everything as root.

Answer (score 1):

There is good article on RHEL doc "[Running a web browser as root](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2094931)" to understand the risks of runing a web browser as root:

> Running a web browser as root is generally a bad idea. Doing so opens your computing environment up to possible attack from outside sources. In this article we'll discuss the vulnerabilities and attack surface when running a web browser as root.
>
> Most security advisories for the Firefox web browser include patches to correct vulnerabilities for remote code execution. These vulnerabilities are exploited by remote code hosted on other websites or by a MITM injection of code.
>
> **The Attack**
>
> When an attack happens, code from the remote web server, or the injected code, is executed on the local computer. Depending on the level of access of the user running the web browser, the executed code potentially has access to whatever data the user has access to. This access could potentially extend beyond the system where the code was executed.
>
> Run as a user and the browser has access to all the user files. Run as root and the browser has access to the entire system. Given the likelihood of any given browser being affected by remote code execution flaws, the number of these types of flaws, and the wide attack surface (nearly every web site should be considered untrustworthy in this context) it is advised to never run a web browser as the root user.